# How to generate unique field for all documents

Tags: mongodb

I want to do something as below:

```js
db.coll.updateMany(
  {}, 
  {
    $push:{
      "newField":new ObjectId()
    }
  }
)
```

I want `newField` to have unique ids for all docs. But that's not the case as `ObjectId`s are generated on driver side.

How can I do this? MongoDB version is 4.2

Comment: "But that's not the case as ObjectIds are generated on driver side." - yep, so update documents invidually, generating a new objectid for each. You can use [bulk writes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/) to considerably speed this up.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks. I wonder why this feature is not possible. I need to add a unique Id for all docs. Currently I'm doing via bulk write to create another collection with this new field which takes 3hours for 10m records. It is too high.

Comment: This does sound too high. Last time I was importing large data set into my mongo I was able to do some 4k inserts / sec on a moderately specced machine. This is unbatched individual writes. Batched writes should be much faster.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I do something as follows. Have 100 reader and 100 writer threads. Threads are handled by akka. Each thread reads a 10k msg and modifies and inserts back to newer collection. Is it expected?

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the actual thing, but try _less_ threads and see how it affects the throughput. If your hardware is not fast enough, all this threading might be incurring more overhead than actual work.

Comment: Sure @SergioTulentsev. I ll check further.

Comment: Add the unique id when you are inserting the documents in the collection in the first place.

Comment: @D.SM I need to update an existing collection for history purpose

Answer (score 1):

Use $exists:false in the query on the field you are adding, execute in a loop until you have zero documents updated.

```
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.foo.insert({a:1})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.foo.update({new:{$exists:false}},{$set:{new:new ObjectId()}})
WriteResult({ "nMatched" : 1, "nUpserted" : 0, "nModified" : 1 })
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.foo.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f1b5bcc74541096256ab898"), "a" : 1, "new" : ObjectId("5f1b5bd574541096256ab899") }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
db.coll.ensureIndex( { newField: 1 }, { unique:true, sparse:true } );
```

Answer (score 0):

For the temporary solution you can try,

```
db.coll.find().forEach(function(doc){
    doc.newField = doc.newField ? doc.newField : [];
    doc.newField.push(new ObjectId());
    db.coll.save(doc);
})
```